# How to built Eclipse plugin with Maven, Tycho and Jython?

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, jython, tycho

I want to create an Eclipse plugin that is able to execute Python code. For this I want to use Jython. Additionally I use Maven for dependencies and want to use Maven for packaging.

**My problem: (Solution added below)**
I'm not able to build with Maven a eclipse plugin which is using Jython. Maven tells "BUILD SUCCESS" but Tycho & jython-compile-maven-plugin doesn't work together. The jython plugin is working because there are two jar as output, the normal jar and the jar with Jython extracted. The Tycho plugin is working because the normal jar is a valid plugin. But the jar with Jython extracted, which is needed, isn't a valid plugin. So how to bundle this 2 plugins correct?

**Questions:**

1. How to bring Tycho + jython-compile-maven-plugin together?
2. Iam using unpack-dependencies to unpack the python libs, but its working only once, if the folder is deleted/renamed/... Maven Update Project never called this again.

Because Maven, Tycho, Jython, M2E is new for me I ...:

- created java project using Jython, packed as runnable jar with Maven, working
- created eclipse plug-in, build with Maven & tycho plugins, working
- created eclipse-plugin using Jython with "BundleShape: dir" without Maven, working

**How to reproduce the problem?**

```
Eclipse Photon, Modeling + installed M2E:
 - Create new Plug-in Project name: ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin, Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
 - [x] This plug-in will make contributions to the UI (and no RC Application)
    - [x] Create a plug-in using one of the templates
      - View contribution using 3.x API
        - View Class Name: SampleView
 - Convert Project to Maven Project
 - Replace POM with given given source
    - Run Maven "Update Project...", refresh workspace after
      - if there are pom errors like "Execution default-compile of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin [...]" do a change anywhere in pom and save (like insert newline, whitespace, tab, ...)
 - Replace SampleView Class with given source (don't delete your package)
 - Open plugin.xml, runtime, add classpath libs/jython-standalone.jar
 - right click pom, run as, maven build..., goals: clean package

 Testing:
 - Put the plugin to eclipse plugin dir, restart eclipse
   - window -> show view -> other
      - Sample Category, Sample View
```

Additionally:
"run as Eclipse Application" doesn't mean that its working if packed.
Iam using Jython-Standalone.

**Edit 1:**
I made some progress. I did not understand correctly how Tycho works at the beginning. Tycho is using the Manifest / build.properties not the pom dependencies. The POM manages not the runtime dependencies, that why I needed to add the jython-standalone.jar to runtime. The jython-compile-maven-plugin isn't needed. I seems most important for Jython that the /Lib folder with python code is at the root point if in a jar. There are many possibilities to solve this, I am using a source folder created with eclipse named "pythonExtracted". The new source folder should now be in build.properties. Every source folder is copied to the root of the jar. The jython-standalone.jar ist in libs/ and is added to classpath manually. If you set "python.home" to the plugin.jar it looks working. But I can't resolve the bundle and the path "." points to the eclipse.exe not the jar like it is if a runnable jar is used.

I don't like that I now have 2 times the Lib folder with the same code. I tried to extract jython into lib/jython and set the runtime classpath. Tried to vary python home path. Nothing worked if the plugin is packed as jar. It really seems like it can only be /Lib inside of the jar. I tried to use Jython (not standalone) in libs but extracted Lib folder from standalone, but PySystemState / PythonInterpreter couldn't be resolved after packaged.

**Solution:**

```
- you need to add libs/jython to runtime classpath manually
- you need to create a source folder named: pythonExtracted (or adjust pom.xml below)
+ working if eclipse plugin packed as jar
+ Maven Update Project prepares the project
- python libs are twice in (extra ~10MB)
```

**Solution: Pom.xml (without M2E config)**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <eclipse-release-url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon</eclipse-release-url>
        <maven-tycho-version>1.2.0</maven-tycho-version>
        <maven-dependency-plugin-version>3.1.1</maven-dependency-plugin-version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eclipse-release</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>${eclipse-release-url}</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.python</groupId>
            <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-dependency-plugin-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution> <!-- JythonStandalone to /libs, strip version -->
                        <id>copyLibs</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                            <stripClassifier>true</stripClassifier>
                            <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/libs</outputDirectory>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.python</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpackPythonLibsFromJython</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeGroupIds>org.python</includeGroupIds>
                            <includeArtifactIds>jython-standalone</includeArtifactIds>
                            <includes>Lib/**/*</includes>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/pythonExtracted</outputDirectory> <!-- has to be a source folder -->
                            <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>macosx</os>
                            <ws>cocoa</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Solution: Pom.xml (with M2E config)**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <eclipse-release-url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon</eclipse-release-url>
        <maven-tycho-version>1.2.0</maven-tycho-version>
        <maven-dependency-plugin-version>3.1.1</maven-dependency-plugin-version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eclipse-release</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>${eclipse-release-url}</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.python</groupId>
            <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-dependency-plugin-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution> <!-- JythonStandalone to /libs, strip version -->
                        <id>copyLibs</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                            <stripClassifier>true</stripClassifier>
                            <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/libs</outputDirectory>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.python</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpackPythonLibsFromJython</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeGroupIds>org.python</includeGroupIds>
                            <includeArtifactIds>jython-standalone</includeArtifactIds>
                            <includes>Lib/**/*</includes>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/pythonExtracted</outputDirectory> <!-- has to be a source folder -->
                            <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Enable the replacement of the SNAPSHOT version in the final product 
                configuration 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-tycho-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <id>package-feature</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}_${unqualifiedVersion}.${buildQualifier}</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includeAllDependencies>true</includeAllDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>-->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>macosx</os>
                            <ws>cocoa</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>validate-version</goal>
                                            <goal>validate-id</goal>
                                            <goal>build-qualifier</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute>
                                            <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                                        </execute>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute>
                                            <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                                        </execute>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-dependency-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [${maven-dependency-plugin-version},)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>copy</goal>
                                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute>
                                            <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                                        </execute>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Solution: Activator.java (set it in plugin.xml)**

```
package examplemavenjythoneclipseplugin.views;

import org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

/**
 * The activator class controls the plug-in life cycle
 */
public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {

    public static Bundle bundle = null;

    // The shared instance
    private static Activator plugin;

    /**
     * The constructor
     */
    public Activator() {
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin#start(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
     */
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        super.start(context);
        plugin = this;

        if (bundle == null) {
            bundle = context.getBundle();
        }
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin#stop(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
     */
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        super.stop(context);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the shared instance
     *
     * @return the shared instance
     */
    public static Activator getDefault() {
        return plugin;
    }
}
```

**Solution: SampleView.java**

```
package examplemavenjythoneclipseplugin.views;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormAttachment;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.python.core.PySystemState;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class SampleView extends ViewPart {

    private static void pythonTest(final String home) {
        final Properties propsPre = System.getProperties();
        final Properties propsPost = new Properties();

        // suppress warning console encoding not set
        propsPost.put("python.console.encoding", "UTF-8"); 
        // if no Lib folder is found, constructor of PythonInterpreter fails, but this isn't useful
        propsPost.put("python.import.site", "false"); 

        // set python home path / cache dir for Jython (just package information)
        propsPost.put("python.cachedir", new File(home, "cachedir").getAbsolutePath());
        propsPost.put("python.home", new File(home).getAbsolutePath());

        // used for our own "System.out" => we can read it later with ease
        final java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream out = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // needed only once in any application before any other Python/Jython code is used.
        PySystemState.initialize(propsPre, propsPost, new String[0]);
        try (final PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();) {
            interpreter.setOut(new java.io.PrintStream(out));
            interpreter.exec("print('Hello World')"); // checks if start is fine
            interpreter.exec("print ' '");
            interpreter.exec("print('importing sys'); import sys; print('done');"); // should work even if Lib not found
            interpreter.exec("print 'prefix:', sys.prefix");
            interpreter.exec("print ' '");
            interpreter.exec("print 'System path:', sys.path");
            interpreter.exec("print('importing os'); import os; print('done');"); // needs access to lib folder
            interpreter.exec("print('Hello World')"); // if anything above fails, null is printed not Hello World

            MessageDialog.openInformation(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), "Output:",
                    out.toString() + "\n" + (home));
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            MessageDialog.openError(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), "Jython failed",
                    out.toString() + "\n" + t.toString());
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        /* 1) Show Python home path
         * 2) make Python home path changable
         * 3) create button to start PythonInit & test
         */
        // I have no clue why, getBundle failed in various situations, the plugin Activator gets the bundle better.
//      final Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin"); // Argument = Manifest.Bundle-SymbolicName
        final Bundle bundle = Activator.bundle; // start(BundleContext context) => context.getBundle()

        // 1 & 2) Create input showing the home path used (fallback "." = not valid in this working version but is vor runnable jar)
        parent.setLayout(new FormLayout());
        final Text input = new Text(parent, SWT.SINGLE);
        FormData d = new FormData();
        d.top = new FormAttachment(parent, 0);
        d.left = new FormAttachment(parent, 0);
        d.right = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
        input.setLayoutData(d);
        try {
            File b = FileLocator.getBundleFile(bundle);
            input.setText(b.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            input.setText(".");
        }

        // 3) create button to start test
        final Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
        d = new FormData();
        d.top = new FormAttachment(input, 5);
        d.left = new FormAttachment(parent, 0);
        d.right = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
        button.setLayoutData(d);
        button.setText("test");
        button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                pythonTest(input.getText());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
    }
}
```

**Solution: Maven Console "mvn clean package"**

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin:ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ D:\Programme\eclipse\modeling oxygen\MDSD-Prototyping\ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin\pom.xml
    [INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon/
    [INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon/
    [INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon
    [INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/photon/
    [INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/photon/
    [INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon/201806271001/
    [INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon/201806271001/
    [INFO] Fetching content.xml.xz from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon/201806271001/
    [INFO] Fetching content.xml.xz from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon/201806271001/
    [INFO] Fetching content.xml.xz from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon/201806271001/ (248,94kB at 247,04kB/s)
    [INFO] Fetching content.xml.xz from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon/201806271001/ (701,55kB at 349,82kB/s)
    [INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin:ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ D:\Programme\eclipse\modeling oxygen\MDSD-Prototyping\ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin\pom.xml
    [INFO] Resolving class path of MavenProject: ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin:ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ D:\Programme\eclipse\modeling oxygen\MDSD-Prototyping\ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin\pom.xml
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] -----
    [INFO] Building ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ---------------------------[ eclipse-plugin ]---------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin ---
    [INFO] Deleting D:\Programme\eclipse\modeling oxygen\MDSD-Prototyping\ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin\target
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:1.2.0:build-qualifier (default-build-qualifier) @ ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin ---
    [INFO] The project's OSGi version is 1.0.0.201812181615
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:1.2.0:validate-id (default-validate-id) @ ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin ---
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:1.2.0:validate-version (default-validate-version) @ ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin ---
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:unpack-dependencies (unpackPythonLibsFromJython) @ ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin ---
    [INFO] Unpacking D:\Programme\.m2\org\python\jython-standalone\2.7.1\jython-standalone-2.7.1.jar to D:\Programme\eclipse\modeling oxygen\MDSD-Prototyping\ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin\pythonExtracted with includes "Lib/**/*" and excludes ""
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:copy (copyLibs) @ ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin ---
    [INFO] Configured Artifact: org.python:jython-standalone:?:jar
    [INFO] Copying jython-standalone-2.7.1.jar to D:\Programme\eclipse\modeling oxygen\MDSD-Prototyping\ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin\libs\jython-standalone.jar
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Programme\eclipse\modeling oxygen\MDSD-Prototyping\ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin\src\main\resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- tycho-compiler-plugin:1.2.0:compile (default-compile) @ ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin ---
    [INFO] Compiling 2 source files to D:\Programme\eclipse\modeling oxygen\MDSD-Prototyping\ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin\target\classes
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Programme\eclipse\modeling oxygen\MDSD-Prototyping\ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin\src\test\resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- target-platform-configuration:1.2.0:target-platform (default-target-platform) @ ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin ---
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:1.2.0:package-plugin (default-package-plugin) @ ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin ---
    [INFO] Building jar: D:\Programme\eclipse\modeling oxygen\MDSD-Prototyping\ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin\target\ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- tycho-p2-plugin:1.2.0:p2-metadata-default (default-p2-metadata-default) @ ExampleMavenJythonEclipsePlugin ---
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 55.097 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-18T17:16:51+01:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I guess, you have to manually unzip the plug-in JAR built by Tycho or build an update site and use _Help > Install New Software..._ (the JAR is unpacked during installation): http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html

Comment: I didn't quite understand the solution, but it helped me to continue looking in the right direction and to find a solution, thank you!